# Get the relative position of text after the CSS text-align styling

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, real-time, text-align

I have aligned some text in an element. Could I get the position in pixels of the text's offset, via JavaScript or jQuery?

The example is below:

```html
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p style="text-align: right; background-color:green; width: 80%;">This text is right aligned.</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Is there a way to know how many pixels of space there are before the starting of the text? In other words, I need to know how much width there is in pixels in the green area before the first letter of "This text ...", in the above example.

More importantly, if I drag the browser and change its width, could I know the space in pixels dynamically?

Answer (score 0):

If you give the text a wrapping element (inside the `<p>`), you can do it by comparing the `offsetWidth` of the wrapper and the `<p>`. If the text is right aligned, any difference in width must be the space on the left side.

To check what the position is after the window is resized, listen to the `resize` event on the window, as done below:

```js
// I've placed the important stuff in this function
// so I can use it as an event handler
function updateWidth() {

  // Get width of the text (requires a wrapping element, such as <span>)
  var innerWidth = getElement('inner').offsetWidth;

  // Get width of surrounding <p>
  var outerWidth = getElement('outer').offsetWidth;

  // Subtract to get the amount of space on the left
  var leftSpace = outerWidth - innerWidth;

  // Output it (since I have nothing better to do)
  getElement('output').innerHTML = 'left space = ' + leftSpace + 'px';

}

// Update the amount of space when the window is resized
window.addEventListener('resize', updateWidth);

// Run the function once to display the amount of space
// before the user has resized the window
updateWidth()


// Just a utility (since I'm not using jQuery)
function getElement(id) {
  return document.getElementById(id);
};
```

```html
<!-- There is a wrapping span here -->
<p id="outer" style="text-align: right; background-color:green; width: 80%;"><span id="inner">This text is right aligned.</span></p>

<!-- This is only for outputting the width -->
<pre id="output"></pre>
```

If there is padding on the parent `<p>` and the parent is set to `box-sizing: border-box`, then also subtract the amount of padding from the parent's width.